# Show Results on View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Im triyng to make some calculation on my View, but i cant show the result out of my @{} block

I have this table.

```
    <!--Table to display registered products-->
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>CODIGO</th>
                <th>NOME</th>
                <th>PRECO</th>
                <th>QUANTIDADE</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {  
                double sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Item2.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Sale", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Item2[i].idProduct)
                            </td>

                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Item2[i].nameProduct)</td>
                            <td>
                                <p>R$@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Item2[i].pricesaleProduct)</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Item2[i].quantityProduct)</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Deletar">
                            </td>
                            sum += Model.Item2[i].pricesaleProduct * Model.Item2[i].quantityProduct;                        
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

<!--I want display "sum" here-->
Total Value: @sum
```

I want to show "sum" out of my table, but trying several variations and a get error!

How can i make it?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The name "sum" do not exist in this current context

Comment: Declare `sum` at the top of your view (before you `<table>` tag)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared sum inside `if(){}` block and hence you're not able to access it. Move it outside like this and it'll work

```
 double sum = 0;

 @if (Model != null)
 {  

      ............
      ............
 }
```